# How extern is working in C, inside function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 33;

int main()
{
    int a = 40;
    {
        extern int a;
        printf("%d\n",a);   
    }
}
```

Output : 33

Can anyone please let me know how Extern is working here ?

Why after declaring variable "a" with extern keyword, access to local variable "a" in main is lost ?

Comment: That so-called duplicate was not useful for this particular question.

Comment: I also don't understand the downvoting. This is a quite a good question (especially now that muggins here has fixed a typo and formatted the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extern` used in this context refers to the variable *at global scope*.

So your `extern int a` refers to the variable at global scope, and *shadows* the automatic `a` declared in `main`.

(The effect is similar to the `::a` of C++.)

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms `extern int a;` declares a variable named `a` that exists somewhere else, usually a different compilation unit. It just tells the compiler: "Trust me, that variable exists and let the linker worry about where it actually is.". It shadows the local variable `ìnt a = 40;`. The linker later looks for the variable and then finds the global `int a = 33;`.

This construct is a way to get back access to global variables that where shadowed.